# React Native debugging on Android Emulator behind a corporate proxy

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, isaserver

I'm new to React-Native. I've created a sample application in my office machine. As we're behind a corporate proxy, I've to set APN (Access Point Name) in Android Emulator in order to gain internet access. Without APN, the development server that's on 10.0.2.2:8081 works fine. But after setting APN in emulator, I understand it would not go to 10.0.2.2:8081.

Now, if I don't set a APN, I've no internet access on emulator, and if I set a APN in emulator, the development server that's on 10.0.2.2:8081 isn't caught by the device.

Any help or workaround would be appreciated.

PS: I've tried running emulator from command line by giving a proxy i.e.

`emulator -http-proxy http://192.168.0.1:8080`

but this didn't even worked in React Development server case.

*Is there someway that we are able to get Internet access on Emulator without using Proxy.*

Answer (score 1):

i solved like this
First of all i run on CMD (i have W7) this command

> "C:\android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full
>   -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -http-proxy http://125.1.1.130:3825

and then in the device i set APN like this

- **Name**: name
- **APN**: apn
- **Proxy**: 125.1.1.130
- **Port**: 3825

and that's all. 

 It works perfectly.

Comment: And now the emulator has internet access as well as development server access?

Comment: Yes, should be.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Please let me know how was it.